# Perl: Parse maillog to get date/recipient in a single regex statement

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to parse my maillog, which contains a number of lines which look similar to the following line:

```
Jun  6 17:52:06 host sendmail[30794]: p569q3sX030792: to=<person@recipient.com>, ctladdr=<apache@host.com> (48/48), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=121354, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [1.2.3.4], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1307354043 x8si28599066ict.63)
```

The rules I'm trying to apply are:

- The date is always the first 2 words
- The email address always occurs between " to=person@recipient.com, " however the email address might be surrounded by <>

There are some lines in the log which do not relate to a recipient, so I'd like to ignore those lines entirely.

The following code works for either rule individually, however I'm having trouble combining them:

```
if($_ =~ m/\ to=([<>a-zA-Z0-9\.\@]*),\ /g) {
  print "$1\n";
}

if($_ =~ /^+(\S+\s+\S+\s)/g) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

As always, I'm not sure whether the regex I'm using above is "best practice" so feel free to point out anything I'm doing badly there too :)

Thanks!

Comment: space characters are not meta in regular expressions, so there is no need to backslash them. Why allow an email address that is zero characters long? Why disallow email addresses that contain a hyphen? Or an underscore? Or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print substr($_, 0, 7), "$1\n" if / to=(.+?), /;
```

Your date is in a fixed-length format, you don't need a regular expression to match it.
For the address, what you need is the part between `to=` and the next `,`, so a non-greedy match is just what you need.

Comment: Ahh very elegant thanks alot! I tend to use regex at every opportunity since I'm trying to immerse myself in it. Is there anyway to incorporate the "maybe <> surrounds the email" into the regex?

Comment: If you mean like stripping them out if they're there: Since non-matching `<>` are very unlikely (the characters aren't allowed in mail addresses without quoting), I'd just go for `/ to=<?(.+?)>?, /`.

Answer (score 0):

To match either with one regex, `or` them using syntax `(regex1|regex2)` together:

```
((?<\ to=)[<>a-zA-Z0-9\.\@]*(?=,\ )|^\S+\s+\S+\s)
```

The outer brackets preserve `$1` being assigned the match.

The look behind `(?<\ to=)` and look ahead `(?=,\ )` do not capture anything, so these regexes only capture your target string.